# Difference of two locale date in jquery

Tags: date, datetime, datepicker

I am getting the date from CJuidatepicker with language such de,en,nl.
Now i need to find the difference between two dates in jquery accordnig to the language selected.

My Code is 
var d = new Date();

```
        var month = d.getMonth()+1;
        var day = d.getDate()-1;

        var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
            ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
            ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;


        var dateString1 = $('#Jobs_valid_date').val();
        var dateString2= output;

        var dateDiff = function ( dateString2, dateString1 ) {
            var diff = Math.abs(dateString2 - dateString1);
            if (Math.floor(diff/86400000)) {
                return Math.floor(diff/86400000);
            } else if (Math.floor(diff/3600000)) {
                return Math.floor(diff/3600000);
            } else if (Math.floor(diff/60000)) {
                return Math.floor(diff/60000);
            } else {
                return "< 1 minute";
            }
        };

        var new_date = dateDiff(new Date(dateString2), new Date(dateString1)); 
        var sum = (parseInt(new_date * feature) + parseInt(fixed))
```

It retuns NAN.. Please help me to solve this

Comment: After using moment.js , Now  I am getting date according to the language I have choose. But I am calculating difference between two dates. One date I am passing from CJuiDatePicker. So My question is how to get the date, month and Year of the date which i have passed via CJuiDatePicker. 

If the site is in german language - the format og CJuiDatePicker date will be 18.02.2014. If the lang is 'en', the format of the date will be 02/18/2014. I need to get the month from this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it from scratch is not recommended for several reasons. If using a library is not a constraint, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). It has methods to calculate date differences. It has internationalization support too. In case your locale is not supported you can add it yourself. If you add a new locale, you are welcome to contribute it to the moment.js community.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this worked for me. I wanted to calculate difference between the 2 dates which the client inputs.

function calculate(start_date,end_date)
{

var t1= start_date ;

var t2= end_date;

// The number of milliseconds in one day

var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

//Here we need to split the inputed dates to convert them into standard format

var x=t1.split(“/”);

var y=t2.split(“/”);

//date format(Fullyear,month,date)

var date1=new Date(x[2],(x[1]-1),x[0]);

var date2=new Date(y[2],(y[1]-1),y[0]);

//Calculate difference between the two dates, and convert to days

numberofDays=Math.ceil((date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/(one_day));

// numberofDays gives the diffrence between the two dates.

$(‘#Input_type_text).val(numberofDays);

}